# Removes words from line after certain word

Tags: python

I have a file which contains line

```
Type sequential IQ,IQN
```

So when ever that line comes i want my output as

```
Type sequential
```

I tried code

```
out = open("file2","w")
Pa =open("file","r")
for line in file:
     If re.sub(r'^(Type+\s+sequential).*$', r'\1', line, re.M):
            print >> out,line
```

This also did not worked.

Answer (score 2):

### Your specific example

The existing answer using `re` will work for one line. However, since you called your variable `lines`, I am assuming you want to work with input e.g.

```
lines = 'Type sequential IQ,IQN\nType sequential IQ,IQN'
```

Possibly as read from a file with `read`. In that case the RegEx needs to be modified as:

```
r'^(Type+\s+sequential).*$'
```

*and* we will need multiline mode, `re.M`, which you've already figured out. One thing to be careful of though, is that `re.M` should be passed as the `flags` keyword argument to `re.sub`, as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

**Important**

*since you don't give the `count` keyword argument, you need to explicitly give the `flags` argument as `flags=re.M`*. This is because `re.M` is actually an `int`, so it is also valid to give it as argument to `count` (try `int(re.M)` in a Python REPL). `count` appears before `flags` in the arg list for `re.sub`, so Python assumes you meant to give a `count` argument. I.e. the call

```
lines = re.sub(r'^(Type+\s+sequential)\s+(\S)', r'\1', lines, re.M)
```

is the same as:

```
lines = re.sub(r'^(Type+\s+sequential)\s+(\S)', r'\1', lines, count=re.M)
```

Which might be a little spooky, if you expected Python to complain about the type of the `count` argument.

**Full Example**

Starting with a file `eg.txt`, with contents:

```
Type sequential IQ,IQN
Type sequential IQ,IQN
```

We then read the file and make the regex substitution as follows:

```
import re

with open('eg.txt') as infile:
    lines = infile.read()
    lines = re.sub(r'^(Type\s+sequential).*$', r'\1', lines, flags=re.M)

    print(lines)
```

After which, you may do as you like with `lines` e.g. write to another file:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(lines)
```

### A more general solution

It may be of interest to you, and others that come after you, to have a general solution to the problem of

> Remove words from line after certain word

Specifically, we want a function to read a file into a string, truncating lines after a certain word (or words, or regex pattern), and return the truncated version as a string.

Here is an implementation:

```
import re


def truncate(after, in_file):
    in_lines = in_file.read()
    return re.sub(rf"^(.*?{after}).*$", r"\1", in_lines, flags=re.M)
```

And usage:

```
with open(__file__) as f:
        print(truncate("in", f))
```

Which gives output (running truncate with its own definition etc. as input):

```
import re


def truncate(after, in
    in
    return re.sub(rf"^(.*?{after}).*$", r"\1", in


with open(__file__) as f:
    prin
```

Which seems about right...

Comment: I tried this. But it not worked. I have added more information in question the way I did. Can you please check and let me know the error i am doing.

Comment: See the edit. Note however that you seem to be confused about how to read and write to a file, as well as print output. If you have separate questions about these then look up the Python docs, or post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

This is using a list:

```
lines = "Type sequential IQ,IQN" # 1
mylist = lines.split() # 2
print(mylist[0], mylist[1]) # 3
```

**1. First line**: define lines.
**2. Second line**: `split` the lines with a space. the result is `['Type', 'sequential', 'IQ,IQN']`
**3. Last line**: print mylist's first item and the second item.

Answer (score 0):

Try slicing the string using index and length.

```
line = 'Type sequential IQ,IQN'
lines = line[:line.index('Type sequential') + len('Type sequential')] 
print(lines)
```

Summary: index finds the string, len determines how long it is, then it splices it off.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your substitution instruction as follows. The last parameter isn't necessary, and instead of `\S` -> `.*`. Also added `$` for convenience and removed `\s+` between the groups.

```
>>> s = "Type sequential IQ,IQN"
>>> lines = re.sub(r'^(Type+\s+sequential)(.*)$', r'\1', s)
>>> lines
'Type sequential'
```

Comment: Probably the OP needs multiline mode because the input spans multiple lines. See my answer for the fix in that case.

Comment: Yes, your answer is more complete, hence the `flags` argument :) Could also be done with list comprehension, but I guess it's less efficient. Thanks!